# Rename multiple columns in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

```
Endo_co=Endo.columns
b_list=Endo_co.tolist()
subo='.[0-9]+$'
Endoo=pd.DataFrame(b_list)[pd.DataFrame(b_list).apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains(subo, case=False).any(), axis=1)] 
col_ind=Endoo.index
Endoo_list=Endoo.values.tolist()
new_col={}
for i in range(len(Endoo_list)):
    new_col[i]=([li[:-2] for li in Endoo_list[i]])
valu=new_col.values()
new_column=list(valu)
Endo.rename(columns = {b_list:new_column}, inplace = True)
Endo = Endo.rename(columns={Endo.columns[col_ind]: new_column})
```

I'm trying to rename multiple columns. But getting "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'". Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As per the official [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html), you must provide a dict-like object as the parameter for the `columns` attribute.

In your particular case, you are trying to set the key and value of your dictionary using lists, hence the reason why you are receiving that error. Below same dummy code reproducing the exact scenario and error.

```
list1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
list2 = ["11", "2", "3"]

dict12 = {
    list1: list2
}
```

To be able to rename multiple columns in a DataFrame, you have to first properly construct the dictionary for the `columns` attribute. Below an example for reference.

```
import pandas as pd

df_columns = ["Column_1", "Column_2", "Column_3"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_columns)

df.head()
# Column_1  Column_2    Column_3

new_df_columns = {
    "Column_1": "Column_11"
}
df.rename(columns=new_df_columns, inplace=True)

df.head()
# Column_11     Column_2    Column_3
```

**EDIT1**
For your particular example, you could run the below dictionary comprehension statement to generate a dict-like object that you can use as input for the rename operation. Please be aware that this only works if both lists are of the same length, and the corresponding column names are at the same index in both lists.

```
b_list = ["Column_1", "Column_2", "Column_3"]
new_column = ["Column_11", "Column_22", "Column_33"]

dict_columns = {b_list[i]: new_column[i] for i in range(len(b_list))}
# {'Column_1': 'Column_11', 'Column_2': 'Column_22', 'Column_3': 'Column_33'}
```